# Scale animation in background from another anchorPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, cgaffinetransformscale

Ive done a Scaling animation for background image with an arrow in it,well by scaling the image(it includes the arrow) meaning its a whole background. it scales from the center of the background. but i want to start scaling from the center of arrow.

i want to achieve this :

[image]

Then to become with scale:

[image]

What i have to change in my code:

```
    self.blueBackground.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1, 1);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
        self.blueBackground.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 30, 30);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

With my current code the scale start from center of background so the arrow end up at the right (out the bounds of screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
- (void)animateArrow
{
  self.blueBackground.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
    ScaleViewAboutPointInBounds(self.blueBackground, arrowCenter, 30);
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  }];
}

static void ScaleViewAboutPointInBounds(UIView *view, CGPoint point, CGFloat scaleAmount)
{
  CGFloat xAnchor = view.layer.anchorPoint.x * CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds);
  CGFloat yAnchor = view.layer.anchorPoint.y * CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds);

  CGFloat xOffset = point.x - xAnchor;
  CGFloat yOffset = point.y - yAnchor;

  CGAffineTransform shift = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-xOffset, -yOffset);
  CGAffineTransform unshift = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xOffset, yOffset);
  CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleAmount, scaleAmount);

  view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(shift, CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, unshift));
}
```

It's probably more general than what you need, and you could do it simpler, but this should work too. Just change the `point` to something that looks like the center of the arrow.